# Count the number of times a sublist is in a list, no matter the order

Tags: python, list, counter

I am sure this questions is already here, but I cannot find the answer. Basically, I need to find the number of times a set of three strings is in a list, let´s say we have:

`list=['a','b','b','c', 'a', 'c', 'd']`

In this case, we have two triplets of `a,b,c` strings. It can be found like this:

`all(x in list for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']) --> True`

But how can I count the number of times this triplet appears in the list, which in the list example would be 2?

Comment: How would you do this without a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Count all of the letters individually, and take the `min` to handle cases where you have more of some letters than others (the `min` is the number of complete triplets, whereas the `max` would include incomplete triplets).

```
>>> my_list = list=['a','b','b','c', 'a', 'c', 'd']
>>> min(my_list.count(x) for x in ['a', 'b', 'c'])
2
```